# How to see list of possible exception in some Class.(C#.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, exception, visual-studio-2005

I have a lot of classes that have been written in C#.NET, and I need to know what exceptions can be thrown by them. How I can do it in Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Great question. I wonder if there's a tool to help with this. Most (but not all) possible exceptions can be determined at compile time if analysis goes deep enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You pretty much *can't*. Firstly, .NET/C# don't have checked-exceptions like Java, and secondly there are a number of *general* exceptions that could happen for any freaky reason.

On a method-by-method basis, you can decorate methods with the exceptions they raise, but this is not guaranteed to be present, accurate or complete.

In general, though, any unexpected* exception should be treated as terminal; just unwind, cleaning up (`using`) etc as you go and propagate the exception - or at least log it if the operation isn't critical.

---

*=I'll leave aside the philosophical discussion of whether an exception should every truly be *expected* as such...

Answer (score 2):

You have to look at the code, it is the only source for this.
It is possible to specify what exceptions can be thrown in xml comments but it is not mandatory, so often this imformation is missing.